# Recover overwritten terminal log output

Tags: scripts, files, data-recovery, log

I accidentally overwrote the log output of the terminal.

What i did was

```
script logfile

commands 

exit
```

and then i accidentally overwrote the file as:

```
script logfile
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a question, but your original file is gone, unrecoverable, deleted. You will have to execute `commands` again.